# One random variable bigger/smaller than another independent

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent. To be concrete, suppose $X$ is $N(0,a)$ and $Y$ is $N(0,b)$. For any scalar c,d with c < d, is there a way to bound the following probability from above in terms of a,b,c,d?

$P(cX<Y<dX)$

Comment: Is this for homework? If so, you should add the `self-study` tag.

Comment: Besides adding the self-study tag, you should read its [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Comment: I don't think there's a need for bounds, it should be possible to evaluate this probability exactly. What's the distribution of $kX-Y$ for some constant, $k$?

Comment: This problem becomes easy once you recognize that $(X/a, Y/b)$ has a circular symmetry and the event $cX\lt Y\lt dX$ describes a congruent pair of (infinite) wedges, implying the result is proportional to the angles of those wedges: drawing a picture may help. For non-normal distributions life is not that simple (because the bivariate distribution no longer enjoys this circular symmetry), but the same picture may suggest reasonable bounds.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ the _variances_ or the _standard deviations_ of the random variables?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas for an explicit computation of the integral. Define $\Delta:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2,cx\lt y\lt dx\}$. Then 
$$P(cX\lt Y\lt dX)=(2\pi ab)^{-1}\iint_\Delta\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2b^2}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2a^2}\right)\mathrm dy\mathrm dx.$$
The inner integral is $\int_{cx}^{dx}\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2b^2}\right)\mathrm dy$, which can be rewritten as $x\int_c^d\exp\left(-\frac{x^2t^2}{2b^2}\right)\mathrm dt$ after a substitution.

Then switch the integrals.

Comment: ... but first make sure you get the normalizing constants correct.  And then consider whether there might be another change of variables that *really* simplifies the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Now that the homework is past due, here is the solution suggested in @whuber's
comments.

Assuming that $a$ and $b$ are the standard deviations of the independent
zero-mean normal random variables, that $c < d$ as the OP says,

$$\begin{align}
P\{cX < Y < dX\} &= P\left\{\frac cb X < \frac Yb < \frac db X\right\}\\
&= P\left\{\left(\frac {ac}{b}\right) \frac Xa < \frac Yb < \left(\frac {ad}{b}\right) \frac Xa\right\}\\
&= P\left\{\alpha \hat{X} < \hat{Y} < \beta \hat{X}\right\}
\end{align}$$
where $\alpha = ac/b < \beta = ad/b$ and $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{Y}$ are
independent standard normal random variables. This is the probability that
the random point $\left(\hat{X}, \hat{Y}\right)$ lies *above* the line
$ y = \alpha x$ and *below* the line $y = \beta x$ in the $x$-$y$ plane,
which is a wedge-shaped region between the two lines of slopes $\alpha$
and $\beta$. But, since
$\left(\hat{X}, \hat{Y}\right)$ have a circularly symmetric joint
distribution, this probability is just

$$P\{cX < Y < dX\} = P\left\{\alpha \hat{X} < \hat{Y} < \beta \hat{X}\right\}
 = \frac{\arctan(\beta) - \arctan(\alpha)}{2\pi}
= \frac{\arctan(ad/b) - \arctan(ac/b)}{2\pi}.$$
Note that the probability cannot exceed $\frac 12$.